# How to return a future<double> - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function called `getAvctUODoss()` which is supposed to return a `Future<double>` but it always return 0.0. If I add a `print('sum');` in my forEach loop, I see that the code works, it's just for the return of it that I have some difficulties. I need the result of this function in another function but, because I can't go further because of this wrong return. I think my mistake is in the declaration of `sum` as a double but I have not idea how to fix this. I searched on Stack Overflow but I only found codes which print the values inside the forEach loop.

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Here is the code of my two functions :

```
  Future<double> getAvctUODoss(String numDoss) async {
    double sum = 0.0; // I think the problem is in this declaration

    affaireCollection
        .document(numDoss.substring(0, 7))
        .collection('dossiers')
        .document(numDoss)
        .collection('rp')
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot) async {
        sum += await documentSnapshot.data['avct'] *
            (await documentSnapshot.data['UO_AT'] +
                await documentSnapshot.data['UO_CH']);
      });
    });
    return sum; //return always 0.0
  }

  Future updateAvctDoss(String numDoss) async {
    await affaireCollection
        .document(numDoss.substring(0, 7))
        .collection('dossiers')
        .document(numDoss)
        .updateData({
      'avct': await getAvctUODoss(numDoss) / await getTotalUODoss(numDoss)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to the following:

```
  Future<double> getAvctUODoss(String numDoss) async {
    double sum = 0.0; 

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await affaireCollection
        .document(numDoss.substring(0, 7))
        .collection('dossiers')
        .document(numDoss)
        .collection('rp')
        .getDocuments();
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot){
        sum += documentSnapshot.data['avct'] *
            (documentSnapshot.data['UO_AT'] +
                documentSnapshot.data['UO_CH']);
    });
    return sum;
  }
```

Since you declared the function `async`, then instead of using `then()`, use `await` to wait for the data to be fully retrieved and then `sum` will be updated and return the data.